# equivalent function for $this->_ci_cached_vars in CI Helpers

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-helpers

I'm creating a custom helper in codeigniter. There is an instance where I check if certain parameter is passed to view.

In view, i can get all the passed variables by using this function:

```
$this->_ci_cached_vars
```

but it returns blank when used in the custom helper.

Is there any equivalent function of this that can be used in the helper?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`_ci_cached_vars` is a property of the `Loader` class. So something like this should work (untested):

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$vars = $CI->load->_ci_cached_vars;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$GLOBALS['CI']->load->get_var('your_key_here')` tested in CI 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if older versions of CodeIgniter support this, but in the v3 release the Loader class has a public method [`get_vars()`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L535) that allows you to read the value of `_ci_cached_vars`.

Although this question is very old it's the first hit on Google that I found while searching for this problem. I hope this post helps someone out who follows the same path on Google as I did! :)